# Execute function within JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I have created a JSON object, but within that object are a list of functions I want to have access to and run as a normal function.  I'm trying to figure out how to accomplish this, but I'm having difficulty.  The following is what I'm doing:

```
Bootstrapper.dynamic = {
    "interaction": function(data) {
        s.linkTrackVars="events,prop2,eVar2,prop32,eVar32,prop33,eVar33";
        s.linkTrackEvents="event2";
        s.prop2="site:social:facebook";
        s.eVar2="D=c2";
        s.prop32=data.tp_type;
        s.eVar32="D=c32";
        s.prop33=data.ct_type;
        s.eVar33="D=c33";
        s.events="event2";
        s.tl(this,'o','interaction');
    }
};
```

Notice the "interaction" function.  That's what I'm trying to fire, but am having difficulty.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: That's a JavaScript object, not a JSON object. To call the function, use `Bootstrapper.dynamic.interaction(yourData);` It's not clear what `s` is supposed to be.

Comment: For reference, `Bootstrapper.dynamic.interaction` is the same as `Bootstrapper.dynamic['interaction']` is the same as `Bootstrapper['dynamic']['interaction']` is the same as `var foo = 'dynamic', bar = 'interaction';` then `Bootstrapper[foo][bar];`

Comment: If I use Bootstrapper.dynamic['interaction'], how do I add arguments to it?

Comment: @pingeyeg invoke as normal with parenthesis with comma-delimited args. However, if you are taking the reference to the function and holding that in a different identifier/parameter name which later is invoked, know the context has changed and hence the `this` object within the function may be different

Comment: Thanks for the help on this one guys.  Not sure why I got -2 points on this, since it was a legitimate question, but whatever.  I'd like to award points, but I cannot yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why exactly do you want to stringify the object? By design, JSON doesn't understand functions. However, Javascript objects do:

```
var x = {
    name:"FirstName",
    age:"21",
    load:function(){ alert('hi') }
};
x.load(); //works
```

If you truly want to convert functions to JSON, take a look at **JSONfn** plugin: http://www.eslinstructor.net/jsonfn/

Comment: I'm realizing now that I didn't mean to call it a JSON object since it's not one.  My bad.